# Bootstrap v3.3.2 Nav Bar Breakpoint

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I am a Bootstrap newbie and I am just getting the layout sorted on a website, including the responsive set up.

The test link is here –

http://www.leedsinkcartridges.co.uk/testrs/index.html

I have it all as I want it, except in iPad Tablet Portrait covering the media points 768px to 991px.

I have copied the Bootly CSS to adjust the media query breakpoint discussed here - bootply.com/105174

Trying this code at the bottom of my styles.css file, it shows the hamburger menu but it displays my nav bar as a bar and not a stack  -

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:991px)
{
   site-navigation
    {
       position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 20px;
        transform: translate(0, -50%);
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
   .nav-invert .site-navigation
    {
        left: 20px;
        right: 0;
    }
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }



}
```

Dropbox link to the files is here -

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cxn91itr8ek2d9k/ipad_portrait.zip?dl=0

The Bootstrap CSS is version v3.3.2

The CSS for the site is a bit of a mess at the moment, so apologies for that!

Any ideas how I fix it as it's almost there!

Thanks,

Dave.

Comment: Hi, can you set up working JSFIDDLE for this. So it would be easier for me to replicate.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kushal,Yes I will get something ready, I will drop you a tweet when I have done it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would not prefer you to grab someone's CSS in your project as a part of best practice.

Other than this, you can follow all 3 approaches mentioned in the [post](http://teckstack.com/change-breakpoints-bootstrap).

Furthermore, I have also added a [comment](http://teckstack.com/change-breakpoints-bootstrap#comment-1959087454) on the same [article](http://teckstack.com/change-breakpoints-bootstrap) and that is the exact solution to your question. This solution doesn't need any CSS change.

Below quoted is the same [comment](http://teckstack.com/change-breakpoints-bootstrap#comment-1959087454) for your reference. Kindly refer it and you may also need to visit [customize and download](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) page of Bootstrap!

> If you want collapsed navbar at 768px (screen-sm-min) then you don't need to customize anything because by
>   default navbar will collapse at 768px in Bootstrap.
>
> But of course if you need it to be collapsed at 992px (screen-md-min),
>   you can change value for "@grid-float-breakpoint" with
>   "@screen-sm-min". In same way you can do for "@screen-lg-min" or
>   "@screen-xs-min".
>
> Thanks.

Hope you find a solution from this.

Thanks.